# Custom made Creditcard Expiry Date field

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to make a POST API request using Alamofire 4.0 and Swift 3.0 but I'm having a tough time with it.

My Postman looks like this:

[image]

And using Basic Auth

[image]

I can't even get my code to compile for now and I've no idea why. This is my function:

```
func testCall(token:String, completionHandler: @escaping ((AnyObject?, Error?) -> Void)) {
    let urlString = Constant.apiUrlString + Constant.apiPostOrderCard
    print(urlString)

    let parameters = ["test" : "test"]
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: self.header).validate().responseJSON { (request, response, result) -> Void in
        switch result {
        case .Success(let value):
            print(value)
            completionHandler(value, nil);
            break
        case .Failure(let data, let error):
            self.handleFailure(data, error: error, response: response, completionHandler: completionHandler)
            break
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you just migrate to Alamofire 4? There are couple of syntax changes, you need to read the migration guide when there is an version update.

Here is the updated code :)

```
func testCall(token:String, completionHandler: @escaping ((AnyObject?, Error?) -> Void)) {
    let urlString =  Constant.apiUrlString + Constant.apiPostOrderCard

    let parameters : Parameters = ["test": "test"]

    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in

        if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
            switch(status){
            case 200:
                if let result = response.result.value {
                    let JSON = result as! NSDictionary

                    // implement your logic here    
                    completionHandler(value, nil);
                }
                break
            case 400:
                   // implement your logic here 
                self.handleFailure(data, error: error, response: response, completionHandler: completionHandler)
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the `Parameters` is Alamofire's object, feel free to use its and the constructor had changed also.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your `encoding: .JSON` to `encoding: JSONEncoding.default` and ensure `parameters` has type `Parameters`:

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: self.header).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let json): //do something
        case .failure(let error): // do something

        }
    }
```